# NSDateFormatter stringFromDate not respecting locale on custom patterns

Tags: iphone, localization, nsdateformatter

What am I doing wrong?

I am trying to getNSDateFormatter to translate custom patterns for dates using the current locale.

Example:

```
    dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormat.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
        output = [self.dateFormat stringFromDate:dateObject];
```

No matter what I change my current locale settings to, I always see the English month abbreviations.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Please `NSLog(@"%@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] identifier])` to confirm you are not working with the English locale.

Comment: So now I am confused.  I am working in the simulator, which is currently set to Italian.  The system 'Done' button seems to be translated...it says 'Fine', but when I log the currentLocale identifier, as you suggested, it says en_US.  Something is not right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it was working all of the time.  I had been leaving my location set to United States and changing only the language.  To get it to work correctly you have to change the location as well as the language.